# ASP.NET MVC Core authentication through parent website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core

On IIS I have a login website which is used to get credentials from user and authenticate him. Authentication is done through:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```

Login application is written in asp.net webapplication.

Now there is another .NET CORE mvc web application which will sit as a child web application to this login website and needs to authenticate through login application.

By default child web application does not comes under login page.

How I can put this web application to use login from parent website?

HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in mvc core child application returns false and can't read logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Traditional web-based auth and specifically FormsAuth utilizes cookies to persist the login state. Cookies are domain-bound, and auth cookies are also *encrypted*. You can only access the cookie in the first place if both apps are on the same domain, and even then, one can only read it if they can both encrypt and decrypt in the same way. The method of encryption has changed between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, so that's out of the window off the bat. ASP.NET used machine keys whereas ASP.NET Core utilizes the Data Protection API.

There's one minor exception, in an ASP.NET MVC 5 site, you *can* utilize the Data Protection API, through its support of OWIN. The two apps, then, can be made to encrypt/decrypt in the same way. However, by the very fact that you're using FormsAuth means that you cannot achieve this. FormsAuth can *only* use machine keys, so you'd have to migrate the legacy app to using ASP.NET Identity at the very least, first.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Login app used by other apps as well. Even .net core app is on same domain . Maybe need to create separate login for this application. Although I will try to find if there is some hack. I was able to access cookie which set global Id but need to extract userid from auth cookie which seems not possible so far

Comment: Not an issue of "so far". It's not possible period. The cookie is encrypted via a machine key, and ASP.NET Core has no way to decrypt it, because it doesn't use machine keys. They're fundamentally different approaches. The only option is to migrate to Identify and update every legacy app to use DataProtection rather than Membership and machine keys. However, that can only be done if the legacy apps are all MVC 5. If that's not the case (or can't be made the case), then you're 100% out of luck.

Comment: FWIW, Membership is deprecated and has been for going on like 7+ years. This is the price you pay for staying on outdated tech long-term. At some point, you have to pay that technical debt or resolve yourself to the fact that things just simply can't be achieved.